# There is a question in my homework that I am unsure how to answer

Tags: sql, database

Using the relational algebra operations, write the following queries on the COMPANY relational database schema shown in the figure below.
(a) Retrieve the address of employees in department 2 who work less than 5 hours per week on the 'ProductX' project.
(b) Retrieve the names and salary of employees who work on every project

[image: schema]

my answer for
A)
π address(σ department = 2 AND hours_worked < 5 AND project =
"Product"(EMPLOYEE ⋈ WORKS_ON ⋈ PROJECT))

B)
πName,Salary(σProject∈(SELECT Project FROM WORKS_ON GROUP BY Project HAVING COUNT(*)=COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeID))(WORKS_ON)

Comment: Upvoting solely because of honesty.

Comment: Tell your teacher to improve the readability of their table field names! This is a horrible schema to work with.

Comment: Also note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh I've found the terms "field" and "column" used interchangeably by the developers and database administrators I've worked with over the years. I'm happy to use "column" but unfortunately my comment is now locked and not editable. Either way, the names are still horrible :)

Comment: @Tony, common misunderstanding, perhaps from Excel users? ISO/ANSI SQL clarifies: "The terms column, field, and attribute refer to structural components of tables, row types, and structured types, respectively, in analogous fashion. As the structure of a table consists of one or more columns, so does the structure of a row type consist of one or more fields and that of a structured type one or more attributes."

Answer (score 0):

First you need to join **EMPLOYEE** ,**DEPARTMENT** **PROJECT** AND **WORKS_ON** tables.For According to table schema ,it must be like this ;

**a)** - `Select EMPLOYEE.Adress from EMPLOYEE JOIN DEPARTMENT on EMPLOYEE.Dno=DEPARTMENT.Dnumber JOIN PROJECT on PROJECT.Dnum=DEPARTMENT.Dnumber  JOIN WORKS_ON on PROJECT.Pnumber=WORKS_ON.Pno where DEPARTMENTS.Dnumber=2 and WORKS_ON.Hours<5 and PROJECT.Pname='ProductX'`

You can do option **b)**-  by looking at what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Establish the relationship between the tables and apply the filters.

For question a) Retrieve the address of employees in department 2 who work less than 5 hours per week on the 'ProductX' project

```
SELECT e.address
FROM employee  e
JOIN department d ON e.dno=d.dnumber
JOIN PROJECT p ON p.dnum=d.dnumber
JOIN (select sum(hours),essn 
      from works_on group by essn
      having sum(hours)<5) w ON w.essn=e.ssn
WHERE d.dnumber=2 
AND p.pname='ProductX';
```

b) Retrieve the names and salary of employees who work on every project

```
SELECT e.fname,e.lname,e.salary
FROM employee  e
JOIN works_on w ON w.essn=e.ssn
WHERE w.pno=ALL(SELECT DISTINCT p.pnumber FROM project p);
```